# How to make our application listen for double tap events from another application in android

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to make our application listen for double tap event triggered in another application in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. You cannot access events like this outside of your application, unless the application you want them from sends a `Broadcast` or something when they occur, which you can then catch with a `BroadcastReceiver`.